# How do I fix a "no matching function for call to 'atoi'" error?

Tags: c++, atoi

All indications tell me this is a ridiculously easy problem to solve, but I can't figure out error telling me the `atoi` function doesn't exist.

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

string line;
int i;

int main() {

    line = "Hello";
    i = atoi(line);
    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
lab.cpp:18:6: error: no matching function for call to 'atoi'
i = atoi(line);
    ^~~~
```

Comment: You should change the `#include <stdlib.h>` to the proper `<cstdlib>` and call `std:: atoi`.

Comment: Please don't use `atoi` unless you are crazy and actually prefer having an error return value be a legitimate result.

Comment: @MaxBozzi That is a good idea, but it wouldn't help here.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nope, but it looks like you got his issue covered :)

Comment: what compiler are you using? Because i think to remember, that there was a broken mingw version (that was used as default with Code::Blocks) with a missing atoi function. Not sure if this still the case with C::B, but it may be. If this is your problem, you have to manually download a newer compiler version and add it to C::B

Comment: @Max: There is nothing "improper" about `#include <stdlib,h>`.  It is part of the C++ Standard Library, see Table 155

Comment: @chris: You are correct that `strtol` has much better error reporting.

Comment: @BenVoigt Even if there is nothing invalid about `<stdlib.h>`, there's no reason to use a C header as opposed to the equivalent C++ version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) expects `const char*`, not an `std::string`. So pass it one:

```
i = atoi(line.c_str());
```

Alternatively, use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
i = std::stoi(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
const char *line = myString.c_str();
```

instead of:

```
std::string line = "Hello";
```

since atoi won't accept an `std::string`